# Google Chrome Plugin: Download Accelerator

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a Google Chrome Plugin that functions as download accelerator? At the very least, I want a plugin that allows me to pause my downloads, save my downloads in the event of browser crash.

Standard Google Chrome download manager will wipe out all the ongoing downloads if Chrome crashes.

Answer (score 2):

See [List Of Download Managers For Google Chrome](http://www.chromeplugins.org/chrome/list-of-download-managers-for-google-chrome/):

> Since google chrome is fairly new as
>   compared to other browsers so not all
>   popular 3rd party download managers
>   support google chrome yet. So just to
>   ease out this problem, i am listing
>   some of the major download managers
>   that have officially got google chrome
>   support till now and which one can
>   easily use without any problems.

The list includes [Internet Download Manager](http://download.cnet.com/Internet-Download-Manager/3000-2071_4-10071618.html), [DownloadStudio](http://download.cnet.com/DownloadStudio/3000-2071_4-10266250.html) and [Download Accelerator Manager](http://download.cnet.com/Download-Accelerator-Manager/3000-2071_4-10411129.html).
The comments also include [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/).

Comment: A desktop client is not something I am looking for. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Integrating with Chrome means that the download manager takes over downloads that you start with Chrome. In effect it replaces the download manager that's built-in into Chrome. These are not "desktop" downloaders. See for example: http://www.clickonf5.org/software/integrate-download-manager-google-chrome/1469.

Comment: @harrymc, still, the fact that the download manager occupies a place in windows registry and has a shortcut on desktop and program shortcut folder is making me very uncomfortable. Which is why I prefer plugin; I don't see it inside my program files folder, it leaves no trace in window registry and it's not visible beyond the browser. Now *that's* what I want.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: It's said that after Free Download Manager is installed, it becomes portable, which is something that you can test. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portable_software#Download_managers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Internet Download Manager](https://www.fileour.com/internet-download-manager-latest-version-free-for-pc/) support of all major browser.  It replaces the download manager that's built-in into Google Chrome. First time I also impress them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Internet Download Manager (IDM)](https://nearfile.com/file-transfer/internet-download-manager/) for it. It has an extension for Chrome which will replace your Chrome's built-in Download Manager and will allow you to download files even Chrome is crashed or closed.

Answer (score -1):

The Default Google Chrome downloader allows downloading, but the downloading speed is very slow. Here is the list of Google Chrome Plugin that functions as a download accelerator and will help you pause or continue the download whenever you want: Download Accelerator Plus, Internet Download Manager,  FlashGet, EagleGet, JDownloader.